# Need to display a text view after selecting an item in picker view

Tags: swift, xcode

I am implementing an application which has a `UIPickerView`. Once the picker view is selected this then passes the data onto the next view controller from the class below called `RecipeViewController`. The label shows on this view controller of what item is selected from the picker view however I now need a text view to also display. How would I implement this into my code below which has two classes?

```
import UIKit

class PickerViewController:  UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var cocktailpicker: UIPickerView!

    var cocktails = ["Mojito","Long Island Iced Tea","Sex On The Beach","Screaming Orgasum","Cosmo","Strawberry Summer Sling","Rosini Royal","Blue Lagoon"]

    var passdata: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.cocktailpicker.delegate = self
        self.cocktailpicker.dataSource = self
        passdata = cocktails[0]
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return cocktails.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return cocktails[row]
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        passdata = cocktails[row]
        //cocktails[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
        print(cocktails[row])
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "seguepicker") {

            if let rvc: RecipeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? RecipeViewController {
                rvc.toPass = passdata
            }
            //var rvc = segue.destinationViewController as RecipeViewController;
            //rvc.toPass = selectedValue
        }
    }

}

import UIKit

class RecipeViewController: UIViewController {

    var toPass:String!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPassedData: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelPassedData.text = toPass
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: If you select a specific item from the picker view I want this to display different text view similar to the label.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

If you choose to use this option, I would consider passing the cocktails array.
There could be cleaner options, like using [enum](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html).

```
class RecipeViewController: UIViewController {

    var toPass:String!
    var cocktails = ["Mojito","Long Island Iced Tea","Sex On The Beach","Screaming Orgasum","Cosmo","Strawberry Summer Sling","Rosini Royal","Blue Lagoon"]

    @IBOutlet weak var labelPassedData: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cocktailImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let image = UIImage(named: "Mojito.png") {
            cocktailImageView.image = image
        } else {
          print("Image is missing")
        }
        labelPassedData.text = toPass
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        switch toPass {
        case cocktails[0]:
            recipeTextView.text = "Lime, sugar, mint..."
        case cocktails[1]:
            recipeTextView.text = "Long Island ingredients..."
        default: 
            recipeTextView.text = ""
        }
       if let 
    }
}
```

Notice that the images names should match the elemets in the array.

Comment: I tried this but am having a thread error when running. Thanks

Comment: Did you connect the text view outlet?

Comment: how would i add an image